# Why generic class<t> with type parameter not getting cast to ParameterizedType

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

```
public class JAXBUtil<T> {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T xmlPathToObj(final String FilePath) throws JAXBException {
         Class<T> classType = ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);    
    }
}
```

Method xmlPathToObj, Class classType = ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]); 
is giving java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2):

[`Class.getGenericSuperclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass())

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.
>
> **If the superclass is a parameterized type**, the Type object returned must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source code.

You are getting the superclass type with this. In your case, you don't defined a superclass so it is `Object`, and `Object` is not a generic class.

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {   
         System.out.println(Test.class.getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
    }
}
```

> `java.lang.Object`

If you extends a class that is parametrized, you can get a correct result :

```
public class Test extends Generic<String>{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         System.out.println(Test.class.getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
    }
}

class Generic<T> { }
```

> `main.Generic <java.lang.String>`

Understand that you need to use this in a non-generic class to actually get a value. In a generic class, you will not be able to recover the type.

```
public class Test<U> extends Generic<U>{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new Test<Integer>().getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
    }
}

class Generic<T> {
    
}
```

> `main.Generic<U>`